# Encrypt and decrypt column in a database on database level without changing the framework

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I got a 3 layer software: database(MSSQL), framework(.NET) and a few clients.

In the database I have a table: `People` inside of the table there is an column `secret` which is string, unfortunately this `secret` is kept in plain string. The idea is to encrypt this secret(not hash), but I cannot and don't want to do it by the framework for severe reasons, but I must do it on the database level.

So the idea is that instead of storing: `I really like pink` I could store for example: `TnfA608JRlWikdLeYkeOXADQi4a3bZZe7Ljchxk1ksU=` and when framework queries the database it gets already decrypted text `I really like pink`.

I have read about master keys in the database and possibility of encrypting column with 3DES, but the information was very vague.

**QUESTION:** Is it possible with few to none changes in the framework to force database to encrypt a column when writing to it and decrypt on reading?

Comment: Check out Sql Server's [Always Encrypted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163865.aspx), it is available starting from version 2016. You can specify encryption down to the column level and query the table as if it were not encrypted (*assuming the connection supplied the correct encryption key*) AND you can still make use of proper indexes on the data.

Comment: @Igor No, I haven't, it looks promissing, however we probably(90% sure) use older version and I can't do nothing about it. I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: If they are using an older version check what their upgrade policy is. Sometimes companies are good about that and will try to keep server versions somewhat current, no sense it reinventing the wheel if there is already a plan in place to upgrade 3 months later. Either way, good luck!

Comment: @Igor I checked and some clients still use MSSQL2008.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but have you looked at [Crypteron's CipherDB](http://crypteron.com/cipherdb) encryption plugin for Entity Framework? It not only takes care of encryption but also adds tamper protection, key management, distribution, roll overs and works with SQL, NoSQL, streams, files, object etc.

Edit: If you're not using EntityFramework, check out the [Crypteron CipherObject NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/Crypteron) package. You can encrypt objects and use the encrypted properties. If you do this at the database access layer, the rest of your logic remains unchanged. This may work for your use case.

Disclaimer: I work there but we do have a **free** community version if that fits your bill.